# Android Deep linking can't catch redirect url

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, deep-linking

Is that possible deep link to be like this
I have link like http://example.com/shortlink
when it is opened to the browser it will redirect to http://example.com/product?id=123
so then in there I will open my app and directly go to product with id 123

I have intent filter like this

> [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
>
> Categories = new[]  {       Intent.CategoryDefault,         Intent.CategoryBrowsable    },
>
> DataSchemes = new[]     {       "http",         "https"     },
>
> DataHost = "example.com",
>
> DataPathPrefixes = new[]    {       "/cat",         "/test",        "/product"  },
>
> DataPath = "/")]

For now the url after redirect it will go to directly open play store so I can't catch it on my intent filter
And also when I try to directly copy paste http://example.com/product?id=123 to browser it also directly go to play store. Can it be filtered via intent filter? If I open the link from another app eg chat application it works as it should (showing dialog popup with my app in there)

Comment: You might find this useful https://danielmuller.me/2013/02/android-open-an-app-from-web-link-or-fallback-to-market

Comment: my problem is a little bit different. it works fine if user don't have the app. but if user have the app it always go to play store even though I already catch the domain in intent filter

Comment: Does your device open the link with Chrome or Firefox? Firefox handles things differently.

Comment: I tried with chrome and not yet tested with another browser

Comment: In your question, you're saying that it opening PlayStore. AFAIK, PlayStore only opens its links (e.g. http://play.google.com/) and not http://example.com type links. It could be that the linked website (http://example.com or whatever) is redirecting you to its PlayStore link. In that case you'll probably have to re-think your solution. I guess you'd need a an API which lets you de-code the shortened URL in your app.

Comment: yes. but I already define example.com in intent filter. it should be catched first by intent filter before it redirected to play store right? So it should be showing the dialog popup first before redirected right?

Comment: If you want to catch the shortened URL then the link I provided earlier should be able to help. Please refer to that.

Answer (score 7):

And Chrome doesn’t launch an external app for a given Intent URI in the following cases.

- When the Intent URI is redirected from a typed in URL.
- When the Intent URI is initiated without user gesture

see more: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents